Are these properties contradictory for a stochastic process?
Let $(X_n)_n$ be a stochastic process. Is it possible to have both that $P(\sup_n X_n < \infty) = 1$ and $E(X_n) \to \infty$ at the same time?
Here is the example I have in mind: let $X_0 = 0$ and for each $n$ let $X_{n+1} = X_n/2$ with probability $1/2$ and $(3X_n+1)/2$ with probability $1/2$ (choices for different values of $n$ are made independently). By induction, it is possible to show that $E(X_n) = n/4$, which to me seems to imply that $X_n \to \infty$ would be expected. However, I have an argument that $\sup_n X_n < \infty$ almost surely, which I don't see a flaw in.
Let $(b_i)_i\in \{ 0,1 \}^\infty$ be iid uniform bits, which are the choices to take $X/2$ or $(3X+1)/2$ at each stage in the $X_n$ process. Almost surely there are infinitely many appearances of $1$ within the sequence $(b_i)_i$; let their indices be enumerated by $(i_k)_k$. Then it can be shown that:
$$ X_n = \sum_{k \ :\ i_k \leq n} \frac{3^k}{2^{i_k}} $$
The increments $s_k = i_{k+1} - i_k$ are independent and geometrically distributed with success probability $1/2$, therefore $i_k$ is approximately normally distributed with mean $2k$ when $k$ is large. In particular, for each $\varepsilon > 0$ it should hold almost surely that $i_k < 2k + \varepsilon$ for all sufficiently large $k$, in which case:
$$ X_n \sim \sum_{k\leq n/2} \frac{3^k}{2^{2k}} = \mathcal{O}\big((3/4)^{n/2}\big) $$
The fact that $P(\sup_n X_n < \infty) = 1$ should therefore follow from a precise version of this argument.
Am I making some error in either of these cases, or is it possible for both of these things to be true at the same time?

For your original question, just let $X$ be a real-valued random variable with infinite mean. Then let $X_n=X$ for all $n$. If you want $X_n$ to have a finite mean for all $n$ you can modify the example to $X_n=\min[X,n]$ for all $n$.

For your example, I cannot follow it. Your sum formula looks flawed. Your sum seems to make $X_n>0$ for all $n\in{1,2,3}$, but what happens if $X_0=X_1=X_2=0$?

@Michael If $i_1 = 3$ (i.e., the first appearance of $1$ is at index $3$, in which case $X_0 = X_1 = X_2 = 0$ and $X_3 = 1/2$), then for $n = 0, 1, 2$ there are no values of $k$ for which $i_k < n$, meaning the sum should be interpreted as an empty sum and thus give the correct value of $0$. Also, your observation has made me realize that the $<$ in the base of the sum should probably be a $\leq$ instead.

If $X_3=1/2$, how can that be realized with your formula, which has a $3^k$ term? Also if $i_1=3$ then $2^{i_1}=2^3=8$. I observe that $3/8 \neq 1/2$.  In general I cannot follow your formula. Anyway your example seems overly complicated.

Yes, it is possible. You are basically looking for a bounded sequence of random variables, which diverges in average. You constructed an intricate instance, I'm not sure it works as intended. Nevertheless, you can find easier examples.
As suggested by Michael in the comment section, you may consider a stationary process, i.e. $X_n = Z \;\forall n$, where $Z$ doesn't possess a mean. For example, a Cauchy distribution does the job $-$ more precisely, a negative unilateral Cauchy variable in order to ensure its boundedness.
